# How do I suppress the "This action cannot be completed" message during external COM calls?

Tags: vb6, com-interop

## Background

I'm working on an application in Visual Basic that calls an out-of-process COM server (a wrappered .NET component written in C#).  This component performs a lengthy calculation (10 seconds plus) and attempting to interact with the GUI (part of the VB6 side) while the calculation is in progress causes the program to emit a message similar to (and with the exact wording of) the following:

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/library/BUSINESS/ATLAS/images_v1/324876/dlo.jpg

Sorry for the crappy quality image, I can't upload a screenie anywhere from work.

## Question

Is there a way to suppress this message, either programmatically or through project or build configuration?

## Addendum 1

Attempting to set App.OleServerBusyTimeout yields runtime error 369 (Operation not valid in an ActiveX DLL).  This is part of an ActiveX dll and nothing I can do can change that.  Is there no other solution except to set that property inside the main application, or trimming down the calls to be less than the existing timeout?

Comment: There's no practical way to implement IMessageFilter in a VB6 app.  You'd better consider fixing the code instead of shooting the messenger.  Use a BackgroundWorker in your .NET code, fire an event in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler to let your VB6 code know that the work is done.

Comment: +1 Hans. The worker method should return immediately, without waiting for the work to finish. Then raise an event when the work does finish, to tell the GUI. Another advantage is that the GUI won't be unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent any message from appearing (for example, if you've changed the cursor to an hourglass) then you want to use [`App.OleRequestPendingTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245850%28v=vs.60%29) and not [`App.OleServerBusyTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245854%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Optionally you could also set an alternate message using [`App.OLERequestPendingMsgText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245848%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). Doing so will present your custom message to the user with only an OK button -- which is much less confusing.

Here is some sample code:

```
' set up special message if user interacts with application while waiting on the
' long-running operation to complete
' see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138066

Dim originalOLEPendingMessage As String
originalOLEPendingMessage = App.OleRequestPendingMsgText
App.OleRequestPendingMsgText = "Please be patient while your request is processed."

Dim originalOLEPendingTimeout as Long
originalOLEPendingTimeout = App.OleRequestPendingTimeout
App.OleRequestPendingTimeout = 10000

On Error GoTo Finally
' Call long-running process here

Finally:
' If an actual error occurred we want to capture all the properties of Err
' so we can re-raise it after we clean up
Dim errNumber As Long
Dim ERRSOURCE As String
Dim errDesc As String
Dim errHelpFile As String
Dim errHelpContext As Long

errNumber = Err.Number
ERRSOURCE = Err.Source
errDesc = Err.Description
errHelpFile = Err.HelpFile
errHelpContext = Err.HelpContext

App.OleRequestPendingMsgText = originalOLEPendingMessage
App.OleRequestPendingTimeout = originalOLEPendingTimeout 

If errNumber <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise errNumber, ERRSOURCE, errDesc, errHelpFile, errHelpContext
End If
```

For a longer discussion, see the Microsoft Knowledge Base article [How To Handle OLE Automation Server Timeout and Synchronization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138066).